# Template parameters simplification

Tags: c++, templates

I am fairly new to C++ (using C++ 2011) and I would like to find a solution for the following problem. I have a class that represents a fonction:

```
class Curve {
private:
    ...
public:
    std::array<double, 3> value(double s);
}
```

I am using that object to pass this function to an algorithm that is represented by a class:

```
template <int n, typename Functor>
class Algorithm {
private:
    Functor f;
    std::array<double, n> a;
public:
    ...
}
```

Then I create the object

```
Algorithm<3, Curve> solver;
```

But the 3 is obviously the 3 coming from the size of the array returned by the method value of any objet of type Curve. I would like to simplify this code so that I can use :

```
Algorithm<Curve> solver;
```

But I have no idea on how to do that. Would you mind giving me a hint ?

Best regards,
Francois

Comment: Take a look at std::Vector. They are comparable to lists of many other programing languages.

Comment: @Nallath no, the size is known at compile-time. `std::array` is the best option.

Comment: I'm a big fan of not over optimizing things (eg; Keeping them modular). But thats probably a personal style thing.

Comment: Nallath. Thanks, but the algorithm is a numerical alorithm to solve a differential equation and many objects array<double, 3> are created and destroyed. It has to happen on the stack and not on the heap. The slowdown is huge if you use a vector (I can't remember but I've tested it and is about 10 times slower).

Comment: Are you sure this is C++? The keyword `class` does not take an uppercase C, and I've never seen `Functor` used as predefined symbol, let alone one that designates an allowed type of template parameter.

Comment: Marc. Yes, it is C++, and as I've said, I am new to this language. As I use an IDE, I never have to type the word class, hence the "mispelling". For functor, this is my mistake. One should read typename Functor. Mistake has been corrected.

Answer (score 8):

Add a member `array_length` or something similar to the `Curve` like classes:

```
class Curve
{
public:
    static constexpr const std::size_t length = 3;

private:
    std::array<double,length> a;
};

template<typename ALGORITHM , std::size_t n = ALGORITHM::length>
class Algorithm
{
    ...
};
```

If you need to allow classic function entities as algorithms, that approach doesn't work since there is no `length` member. Other way could be to create a metafunction `data_length`
which given a algorithm function `F` returns the length of the data:

```
template<typename F>
struct length;

//Specialization for Curve class:
template<>
struct length<Curve> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t,3>
{};
```

And then:

```
template<typename F , std::size_t n = length<F>::value>
struct Algorithm
{
   ...
};
```

**EDIT:** Like in any other template, to implement the method specify its template parameters:

```
template<typename F , std::size_t N>
void Algorithm<F,N>::execute()
{
    _f();
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/eEY821) is a running example.

Comment: Thanks Manu, but I can't make it work as I don't know how to implement the methods for Algorithm. I've tried : template<typename Functor, int n> Algorithm<Functor, n>::method(....). But it does not work. I've tried a few other things but it does not work too.

Comment: @Manu343726 "Other way could be to create a metafunction **data_length**" -> you use `length` in your example. Also *metafunction* feels not the best term since there is not really any function.. metatype maybe? Beside that, there's a small inconsistence with `N` and `n`. But +1 for this nice & complete answer.

Comment: @Hiura: metafunction is a common term for this sort of thing.  A "thing" that takes inputs and has a result.  The inputs are template arguments, and the result is in the `value` member, but it's treated like a function.  In C++11 this has been partially replaced with `constexpr`, but `constexpr` can't really take types, where template "metafunctions" can take and "return" types.

Answer (score 1):

You could "pass" the 3 in an enum member like this:

```
class Curve {
public:
   enum { arity = 3 };
   std::array<double, arity> value(double s);
};

template <typename Functor>
class Algorithm {
private:
   std::array<double, Functor::arity> a;
};

Curve curve;
Algorithm<Curve> solver;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `decltype` to get the return type of `value`, and [`std::tuple_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size) to find out how big it is ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd5cae7f9a02b43e)):

```
template <typename Functor>
class Algorithm {
private:
    Functor f;
    static const std::size_t n =
      std::tuple_size<decltype(f.value(0.))>::value;
    std::array<double, n> a;
public:
    // ...
};
```

[or if you simply want `a` to have the same type that `value` returns](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3f074d00ae9c785):

```
template <typename Functor>
class Algorithm {
private:
    Functor f;
    decltype(f.value(0.)) a;
public:
    // ...
};
```

or if you might someday want to use functions of a different type - say `int` or `long long` or whatever - [you can ask for the return type of `f.value` when invoked with a default-constructed value of whatever its argument type happens to be](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8f6d21d39acee3e):

```
template <typename Functor>
class Algorithm {
private:
    Functor f;
    decltype(f.value({})) a;
public:
    // ...
};
```

Comment: That's another very nice option that makes the implementation of Functor easier.